# Проблема создания БД на heroku

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, heroku, psql

Заливаю свое приложение на heroku, код уже там, однако нужно переместить туда структуру бд postgresql. Выцепил из pgadmin4 sql файл, пробую запустить его на сервере (heroku pg:psql --app  < create_db.sql), однако выдает ошибку.

```
ERROR:  permission denied to create database
\connect: неверный номер порта: "="
 !    psql exited with code 2
```

Нагуглил что нужно авторизоваться в postgres, однако при попытке ввести пароль (из pgpass.conf) выдает ошибку

```
psql
Пароль:
psql: ВАЖНО:  пользователь "1" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)
```

Собственно вопрос в том, как мне узнать этот пароль (вроде пишут что он должен быть в файле ) (система - windows) или какие другие пути решения проблемы у меня есть. Ниже код, создающий бд, на случай если ошибка в нем.

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS cursach;
--
-- TOC entry 2826 (class 1262 OID 16393)
-- Name: cursach; Type: DATABASE; Schema: -;
--

CREATE DATABASE cursach WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'Russian_Russia.1251' LC_CTYPE = 'Russian_Russia.1251';

\connect cursach

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- TOC entry 1 (class 3079 OID 12924)
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -;
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;


--
-- TOC entry 2829 (class 0 OID 0)
-- Dependencies: 1
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -;
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';


SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- TOC entry 198 (class 1259 OID 16404)
-- Name: autors; Type: TABLE; Schema: public;
--

CREATE TABLE public.autors (
    "autorId" integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    dateofbirth date,
    dateofdad date
);

--
-- TOC entry 197 (class 1259 OID 16402)
-- Name: autors_autorId_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public;
--

ALTER TABLE public.autors ALTER COLUMN "autorId" ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME public."autors_autorId_seq"
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);


--
-- TOC entry 196 (class 1259 OID 16394)
-- Name: books; Type: TABLE; Schema: public;
--

CREATE TABLE public.books (
    isbn bigint NOT NULL,
    cost integer NOT NULL,
    storage integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    title character varying NOT NULL,
    author character varying NOT NULL,
    publick character varying DEFAULT 'нет информации'::character varying,
    about character varying DEFAULT 'нет описания'::character varying,
    genre character varying,
    creationyear character varying
);

--
-- TOC entry 202 (class 1259 OID 24622)
-- Name: books_isbn_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public;
--

ALTER TABLE public.books ALTER COLUMN isbn ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME public.books_isbn_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);


--
-- TOC entry 199 (class 1259 OID 16415)
-- Name: catigories; Type: TABLE; Schema: public;
--

CREATE TABLE public.catigories (
    catname character varying NOT NULL
);

--
-- TOC entry 200 (class 1259 OID 24603)
-- Name: users; Type: TABLE; Schema: public;
--

CREATE TABLE public.users (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    email character varying NOT NULL,
    passhash character varying NOT NULL,
    fullname character varying NOT NULL,
    phone bigint,
    isadmin boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL
);

--
-- TOC entry 201 (class 1259 OID 24611)
-- Name: users_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public;
--

ALTER TABLE public.users ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME public.users_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);


--
-- TOC entry 2697 (class 2606 OID 16411)
-- Name: autors autors_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public;
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.autors
    ADD CONSTRAINT autors_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("autorId");


--
-- TOC entry 2695 (class 2606 OID 24614)
-- Name: books books_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.books
    ADD CONSTRAINT books_pkey PRIMARY KEY (isbn);


--
-- TOC entry 2699 (class 2606 OID 24610)
-- Name: users users_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.users
    ADD CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- TOC entry 2828 (class 0 OID 0)
-- Dependencies: 6
-- Name: SCHEMA public; Type: ACL; Schema: -; 
--

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO PUBLIC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй нажать на аддон БД на странице проекта. Далее перейти в "Settings" -> "Database credentials". Там находятся данные пользователя и пароль